Transfinite induction and consistency statements
I'm interested in learning more about precise what transfinite induction results are equivalent to various consistency statements in arithmetic. Focusing on induction up to $\epsilon_0$, I see an interesting couple of results in Arai's book Ordinal Analysis and an Introduction to Proof Theory (pp. 99-100... would appreciate it if anyone has another reference for these)

$\{\mathsf{Con}^n(\mathsf{PA}): n\in\omega\}$ is equivalent to the rule $$\dfrac{\forall \beta < \epsilon_0((f(\beta)<\beta \to B(f(\beta)))\to B(\beta))}{\forall\beta < \epsilon_0B(\beta)}\operatorname{\mathscr{E}^\omega-TI_{\epsilon_0}}$$ for any primitive-recursive $f$ and $B$ (which may have parameters)
$ \operatorname{\sf 1-Con(PA)}$ is equivalent to the statement $\mathscr{E}^\omega DS_{\epsilon_0}$ that there is no primitive-recursive decreasing sequence of ordinals $<\epsilon_0.$

Here, $\mathsf{Con}^0(\mathsf{PA}) :=\top$ and $\mathsf{Con}^{n+1}{\mathsf{PA}}=\mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{PA} + \mathsf{Con}^n(\mathsf{PA}),$ and $ \operatorname{\sf 1-Con(PA)}$ means consistency of $\sf PA$ plus all true $\Pi_1^0$ sentences, $<$ is the standard arithmetical implementation of the ordering of $\epsilon_0,$ and the equivalence in each case is over $I\Sigma_1.$
Clearly, from the consistency side, the equivalent statements in 2 are strictly stronger than those in 1, and it makes sense to me on the transifinite induction side as well, since a failure of $\operatorname{\mathscr{E}^\omega-TI_{\epsilon_0}}$ gives a p.r. $f$ that you can iterate to get a p.r. infinite descreasing sequence, whereas the natural $f$ and $B$ that you might try to make out of a p.r. infinite decreasing sequence are not even computable, so the reverse is unlikely.
However, I'm getting very confused by the proofs of the hard directions (induction -> consistency) of these (pp. 121-130 - note Arai proves things in generality beyond $\epsilon_0$, but I'll stick to $\epsilon_0$). The upshot is that, similarly to Gentzen's consistency proof for PA, a sequent calculus with ordinal labels for $\mathsf{PA}(\mathscr{E}^3)+\forall x \lnot B(x)$ (where $\forall x\lnot B(x)$ is $\Pi_1^0$) is developed and it's shown that there are primitive recursive reduction functions that take proofs of the empty sequent (of a certain form) to proofs with smaller ordinals, provided $\forall x \lnot B(x)$ is true.
On a high level, this is familiar to me, e.g. I know the proofs of $\sf Con(PA)$ using $\omega$-logic are typically actually proofs of $\operatorname{\sf 1-Con(PA)}$ since the leaves can really just be any true $\Delta_0$ sentence $\varphi(n)$, and that the proof can even be generalized using partial truth predicates to obtain proofs of the uniform reflection schema (or, really, in the spirit of the results in question, a proof that transfinite induction on arithmetic predicates is equivalent to the reflection schema).
But when it comes to these finer grained results I'm confused. Arai's proof of 1 is by induction on $n$. We assume $\mathsf{Con}^n(\sf PA)$ as an induction hypothesis, which is then a true $\Pi_1^0$ sentence and then use (an improved version of) $\operatorname{\mathscr{E}^\omega-TI_{\epsilon_0}}$ to show there can't be any proof of the empty sequent from $\mathsf{PA} + \mathsf{Con}^n(PA),$ i.e. $\mathsf{Con}^{n+1}(\sf PA).$
But it seems like the only feature of $\mathsf{Con}^n(PA)$ we used is that it is (by induction hypothesis) a true $\Pi_1^0$ sentence. So why is this not really a proof that $\operatorname{\mathscr{E}^\omega-TI_{\epsilon_0}}$ implies $\operatorname{\sf 1-Con(PA)}$? Of course, it can't be since we've already established that the latter is strictly stronger.
My guess is that this really only shows we can prove (in $I\Sigma_1 + \operatorname{\mathscr{E}^\omega-TI_{\epsilon_0}}$) the schema $\varphi\to \mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{PA} + \ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$ for $\varphi\in \Pi_1^0$ and the extra strength in $2$ comes from internalizing the quantifier over $\Pi_1^0$ sentences?
Is this right? I realize this may be a bit technical, but is there a quick explanation of why you can get an p.r. decreasing sequence of ordinals when you work with an arbitrary $\Pi_1$ sentence and you can only upgrade to a violation of $\operatorname{\mathscr{E}^\omega-TI_{\epsilon_0}}$ when you're working with an explicit formula from the metatheory? (Or just an explanation of what's actually going on if I'm way off here?) Finally, is there a good reference other than Arai's book for these results and others along the same lines?
